# How to write an Automation Test before the code is written?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, ui-automation

I have a question that I find difficult to answer or to get an example of.

I am new to automation testing and have been asked to write out automation tests for tasks where the development code for that particular feature has not even been written yet, so we are looking at a red > green test.

I have tried a few approaches to this with little success.

1. I have tried to mock the test steps in a comment but this seems to be duplicating or being redundant work as another automation tester will just remove the comment and do it in their own way (no point in me doing it, to begin with).

   ```
   @Test
   public static void testCase1(){
   try {
   /*
     Test Case comments
   */
   }catch (Exception e){
    fail("Not yet implemented");
   ```

   }
2. Another approach was to make the tests as a step scenario but writing out the method and the passing strings or ints as needed when creating the method with a comment block to describe the step and the purpose. (the same result as above, and with this approach, I noticed that unless I have a complete understanding of the code already in place I am creating duplicate methods).
3. My third option was to write the test case out as far as possible but without any code to latch on to or visual process from the task or user story its difficult to accurately plan the steps out.

If anyone has any experience with this, its part of a shift left approach where automation begins as dev work begins, I would greatly appreciate any tips or examples you might have.

I am also a manual tester hence why I am writing the cases out, taking a manual test case (1st edition of the test case) and porting to the UI Automation Framework (Java, Selenium) which is the 2nd edition of the test case (duplicating work).

Comment: Perhaps you should start by talking to your supervisor and ask them what they expect you to do. You should also talk to the other automators because they need to understand what you are attempting to do and you need to understand why they are changing your code. You are either doing it in a way they don't understand or is wrong or they aren't aware of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Writing out a scenario as a manual test case and then automating those steps is not duplicating work. It's building a requirements doc for your script and the manual test case will likely be used by the manual test team until the scripts are completed.

Comment: @JeffC Oddly enough I am the Manual Test Team haha, But I get your Point, My main issue is that I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, I'm sure with the written comment block they should be able to understand whats going on? 

Just unsure if im taking the right approach?

Comment: Talk with them and tell them what you are trying to do and what they expect. They should be able to tell you the expected (right?) approach.